# Pros and Cons of explicit data conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Does any of you guys use explicit data conversion in JavaScript?
For example:

```
//ModificationAllowed is an integer (1 or 0) value from registry
canModifyRecord = Boolean(application.settings('ModificationAllowed'));
if (canModifyRecord) {
   ... do something
}
```

I want to keep my code as clean as possible but maybe explicit conversion is redundant?

Comment: Good question, but VTC because this is entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. It all depends on the context.

If I'm fetching data for a *model* representation, then yes. I'll make sure the data I store is correctly typed.

If I do calculation with data coming from the user or a server, then yes. I convert everything to `Number()` or I `parseFloat` them.

But for boolean check, if my check is localize and not used elsewhere in the application, then I usually don't do the conversion for brevity sake. But ensuring correct type (with the `!!` hack for example) cannot harm.

So as a rule of thumb:

- Is the data to be reuse elsewhere? Then ensure a correct type.
- Is the data scope limited to the current method/function? Then, only convert if it brings real value (like calculation). Otherwise, type automatic conversion is usually ok.

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a boolean is redundant if you only use that variable as the condition of an `if` conditional, as you do here. In ECMAScript terms, `if` already [converts its condition to a boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) using ES5's [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which is the [same mechanism used by `Boolean(arg)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.1.1).

Other cases *will* be affected by the conversion, notable in equality tests (whether strict or non-strict):

```
"foo" == true            // false
Boolean("foo") == true   // true
```

This is because the behavior of the [non-strict equality algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) is heavily type-dependent. In particular, see step 6 and 7 for boolean-to-other comparison behavior, which casts the non-boolean operand to a number.

Comment: Thanks, when would you use conversion?

Comment: Great answer only because it renders the point of debate in this question moot.

Comment: @Maximus Added a brief example when it does make a difference.

Comment: @apsillers When you do `variable === true` etc

Comment: @apsillers, thanks. But these are a type conversion because of necessity, while my case is about doing conversion on purpose explicitly where JS would do it implicitly. Can you come up with any case when you would do that? I understand in the case I provided explicit conversion is overhead

Answer (score 1):

Using `!!` converts a variable to a boolean nice and easily for me

```
canModifyRecord = !!application.settings('ModificationAllowed');
if (canModifyRecord) {
   ... do something
}
```

Comment: This kind of code is not something that human should read. If you want to cast to boolean at least use `Boolean()`, the outcome is the same.

Comment: It looks useless : it evaluates the same in `if` with or without `!!`.

Comment: @Pavlo I disagree. In my humble opinion explicit coercions are more readable than using constructors. I always use `!` and `!!` over `Boolean` to coerce values into booleans, unary `+` and `-` over `Number` and `parseFloat` to coerce values into numbers and `(+"")` over `String` and `.toString` to coerce values into strings. To me punctuators are more readable than constructors but then again I guess that is just a matter of preference. It's no reason to downvote an answer.

Comment: @Neal, so in my case you would use explicit conversion too?